# php equivalent to Twig's "ignore missing" in include statement

Tags: php, twig, laravel-blade

Specifically, I want to be able to achieve the following lines of code in a blade.php file, instead of by using twig's templating.

[Samples from Twig's documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html)

```
{% include (['A.html', 'B.html']) ignore missing %}
{% include (['A.html', 'B.html'])  ignore missing with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
{% include (['A.html', 'B.html'])  ignore missing only %}
```

I know what I need will look something like this

```
@include( (['A.html', 'B.html']) --ignore missing with-- {'foo': 'bar'})
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP this is the difference between `include` and `require`. `require` will generate a fatal error if the file doesn't exist, `include` will generate a warning and continue. You can suppress the warning with `@`.

```
@include 'filename.php'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@includeIf` in blade to include a file that may or may not exist:

```
@includeIf('view.name', ['foo' => 'bar'])
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews